A sequence of conformal metrics with bounded negative curvatures on the disc
Let $\mathbb{D}$ denote the unit disk, and let $h_{-1}$ be the unique hyperbolic metric on $\mathbb{D}$ which is conformal to $dz^{2}$.
Take a sequence of smooth complete metrics $h_{n} = e^{\rho_{n}} h_{-1}$ conformal to the hyperbolic metric that have curvatures in an interval of the form $\left[-M, -m\right]$ for some positive real numbers $m$ and $M$.

Is it true that the sequence $h_{n}$ must converge (up to extracting a subsequence) in the $C^{\infty}$ sense on compact subsets of $\mathbb{D}$ to some complete metric $h$ on the disk? If not, are there any additional assumptions that would make the statement true?

We know that the curvatures $K_{n}$ of $h_{n}$ are given by the formula $K_{n} = e^{-\rho_{n}}(\Delta_{h_{-1}}\rho_{n} + 1)$, where $-\Delta_{h_{-1}} \rho_{n}$ is the Laplacian of $\rho_{n}$ with respect to the hyperbolic metric $h_{-1}$. Much has been said about this elliptic PDE, but I don't know if this might help for the statement that I am asking about.

Your metrics $h_n$ are not assumed to be smooth, so there is no reason to expect a $C^\infty$ covergence, even when the sequence is constant ($h_n=h$ for all $n$). And of course smooth metrics can converge to a non-smooth one, which also prevents them from converging in $C^\infty$ sense.

Also complete metrics can converge to a non-complete one in $C^\infty$ on compact subsets.

I have edited the question, the metrics are assumed to be smooth.

It does not help, since smooth metrics can converge to a non-smooth one.

I see, thanks. What if we add stronger assumptions, like the curvatures of $h_{n}$​ converging in $C^{\infty}$ to some smooth function ?
